# Mapping of values from nested dictionary to data frame does not work properly

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dict (contains column and value) and I am trying to replace/map the values to a data frame. It looks like this:

```
dict = 
{ 
'customer_id': { '1': '47598374539', '2': '859082093'}, 
'age': { '1': '55+', '2': '25'}, 
'gender': { '1': 'male', '2': 'female'}
}
```

Now, I want to replace the values with the corresponding column in this data frame:

```
df=
customer_id | age | gender | other columns..
1           | 1   | 1      | something
2           | 2   | 1      | something
```

So that it looks like this:

```
df=
customer_id | age | gender | other columns..
47598374539 | 55+ | male   | something
859082093   | 25  | male   | something
```

I tried the `df.replace(dict)` but somehow not all values were changed (only a subset) and I wonder if it has to do that the same key exists multiple times in my nested dict (but for a distinct column)?

What seems to be the best path?

Comment: What are the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: I don't really see the problem here, just issuing `pd.DataFrame(dict_here)` should get the output you want?

Comment: @DaniMesejo do you mean the type in the data frame or in the dict?

Comment: @HampusLarsson The issue is that many values were indeed replaced BUT there were somehow some for which it could not find any match. I checked and in fact there should be one, so not sure why this works only partially..

Comment: In the datafram. The reason I ask is because the keys in your inner dictionaries are strings, and pandas could be transforming your gender column to int, hence not replacing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the mapping will be confused by multiple match for each key in your dictionnary,
You need to use `replace` on each column,
so :

```
for col in df.columns :
   df[col] = df[col].replace(dict[col])
```

---

Also for info :

You can create a pd.DataFrame from a dictionary using pandas.DataFrame.from_dict, in your case :

```
import pandas as pd
your_dict = { 
'customer_id': { '1': '47598374539', '2': '859082093'}, 
'age': { '1': '55+', '2': '25'}, 
'gender': { '1': 'male', '2': 'female'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict)
print(df)
```

will output :

```
Out[6]: 
   customer_id  age  gender
1  47598374539  55+    male
2    859082093   25  female
```

Comment: thanks but there is still a step missing in that replacing the values of the "master" data frame, right?

Comment: Indeed, I updated my answer to fully answer your question